# @State variable not updating childview when value changes

Tags: swiftui, state

I produced this minimal code below

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var lists = [
        [
            "randomString": UUID().uuidString,
            "images": [
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=1",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=2",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=3"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "randomString": UUID().uuidString,
            "images": [
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=4",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=5"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "randomString": UUID().uuidString,
            "images": [
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=6",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=7",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=8",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=9",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=10",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=11"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "randomString": UUID().uuidString,
            "images": [
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=12"
            ]
        ],
        [
            "randomString": UUID().uuidString,
            "images": [
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=13",
                "https://source.unsplash.com/random/200x200?sig=14"
            ]
        ]
    ]
    @ObservedObject var changeObserver = ChangeObserver()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0..<lists.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    let eachList = lists[index]
                    ListView(parent: self, index: index, eachList: eachList, changeObserver: changeObserver)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeView(_ index: Int) {
        lists.remove(at: index)
        changeObserver.changeCount += 1
    }    
}

struct ListView: View {
    
    let parent: ContentView
    let index: Int
    let eachList: [String: Any]
    @ObservedObject var changeObserver: ChangeObserver
    @State var listModels: [ListModels] = []
    @State var currentIndex = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        let randomString = eachList["randomString"] as! String
        let images = eachList["images"] as! [String]
        VStack {
            Text(randomString)
            CarouselImageView(index: $currentIndex, imageList: listModels) { listModel in
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    let imageUrl = listModel.imageUrl
                    let url = URL(string: imageUrl)!
                    let size = proxy.size
                    ZStack {
                        AsyncImage(url: url)
                            .frame(width: size.width, height: size.width)
                    }
                    .frame(width: size.width, height: size.width)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(7)
                    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7).stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 4))
                }
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40)
            .onReceive(changeObserver.$changeCount) { _ in
                var listModels: [ListModels] = []
                for imageUrl in images {
                    listModels.append(ListModels(imageUrl: imageUrl))
                }
                self.listModels = listModels
            }
            Button {
                parent.removeView(index)
            } label: {
                Text("Remove")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .font(.system(size: 17))
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
    
}

class ChangeObserver: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var changeCount = 0
    
}

struct ListModels: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var imageUrl: String
    
}

struct CarouselImageView<Content: View, T: Identifiable>: View {
    
    var spacing: CGFloat = 10
    var trailingSpace: CGFloat = 50
    var reducer: Int = 70
    @Binding var index: Int
    var imageList: [T]
    var content: (T) -> Content
    @GestureState var offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var currentIndex = 0
    
    init(index: Binding<Int>, imageList: [T], content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.imageList = imageList
        self._index = index
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let adjustmentWidth = (trailingSpace / 2) - spacing
            let width = proxy.size.width - (trailingSpace - spacing)
            HStack(spacing: spacing) {
                if imageList.count == 1 {
                    Spacer()
                }
                let _ = DispatchQueue.main.async {
                }
                ForEach(0..<imageList.count, id: \.self){ i in
                    let item = imageList[i]
                    let indexToCI = abs(i - currentIndex)
                    let liner = CGFloat((indexToCI > 2 ? 2 : indexToCI) * reducer)
                    let proxyWidth = proxy.size.width - trailingSpace - liner
                    content(item)
                        .frame(width: proxyWidth, height: proxyWidth)
                }
                if imageList.count == 1 {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, spacing)
            .offset(x: currentIndex.maxOffset(reducer: reducer, width: proxy.size.width, spacing: spacing, trailingSpace: trailingSpace) + (currentIndex != 0 ? adjustmentWidth : 0) + offset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .updating($offset, body: { value, out, _ in
                        out = value.translation.width
                    })
                    .onEnded({ value in
                        let offsetX = value.translation.width
                        let progress = -offsetX / width
                        let roundIndex = progress.rounded()
                        currentIndex = max(min(currentIndex + Int(roundIndex), imageList.count - 1), 0)
                        currentIndex = index
                    })
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        let offsetX = value.translation.width
                        let progress = -offsetX / width
                        let roundIndex = progress.rounded()
                        index = max(min(currentIndex + Int(roundIndex), imageList.count - 1), 0)
                    })
            )
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: offset == 0)
    }
}
```

The purpose of this is that when I click the `Remove` button on `ListView` it will call a method `removeView` from it's parent view `ContentView` which will delete the `index` passed from `@State var lists` then the view is updated since it depends on `@State var lists`

When I click the `Remove` button with `index` of `0`, the view is removed and `ContentView` updates the child view `ListView` as expected.

**But the problem is that the images which is displayed in `CarouselImageView` don't update.**

I added the `randomString` text so you can actually notice the update on the `ListView` when  `@State var lists` changes

So for instance, I click the `Remove` button on `ListView` of index `0`, the view goes away but then the `CarouselImageView` don't get updated, that means after removing the view at `0`, the view goes away, but the images don't go, they replace the images at view `1` and the images at view `1` replaces the images at view `2`... That's how it keeps going

So to verify where the bug is coming from, I tried printing out the `listModels` of `ListView` after updating it

```
.onReceive(changeObserver.$changeCount) { _ in
    var listModels: [ListModels] = []
    for imageUrl in images {
        listModels.append(ListModels(imageUrl: imageUrl))
    }
    self.listModels = listModels
    print(self.listModels) // check if the listModels is updated
}
```

And the result came out as expected. Then I tried the same on `CarouselImageView`

```
init(index: Binding<Int>, imageList: [T], content: @escaping (T) -> Content) {
    self.content = content
    self.imageList = imageList
    self._index = index
    print(self.imageList) // this still prints the old result
}
```

But I still get the old result printed out.

I have no idea why this is happening. I thought `@State` variable was supposed to update all views associated with it when the value changes, so why is `@State var listModels: [ListModels] = []` not doing so?

I also tried changing the `var imageList: [T]` on the `CarouselImageView` to `@Binding` which I know is unnecessary because the `CarouselImageView` don't update its value, but I stil get the same result. And changing `var imageList: [T]` to `@State` but the images don't show up at all

Comment: You can't store references to `View`s like this in SwiftUI (`let parent: ContentView`). `View`s are value types, not reference types. If you want shared state, it must be stored in the parent and passed down to the child -- child views can't reach back up to the parent like you're attempting to do.

Comment: @jnpdx... Just like I said, it's a minimal reproduction code, not the actual code. I used a `protocol` in my actual code. I couldn't implement it here so I don't make the code bulky

Comment: Using a `protocol` doesn't change the concept that you can't store a reference to a view and call a function like `removeView` from the child like that (unless you pass a closure).

Comment: `ForEach` is not a for loop

Comment: After commenting out the `.offset` modifier of the `CarouselImageView` (it was throwing errors), I was able to produce the same problem. I tried using a `@Binding var` for `lists`, but that changed nothing. The app behaves as expected if you hit the last `ListItem` `Button`, but if you hit any other `Button` it acts like you hit a different `Button`.
Upon examining what was printed to the console, nothing was actually deleted, only the images got moved around, and new `randomNumber`s were issued.